# Get the current dot net version of my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, version

How do I get the running dot net version of my asp.net application.

I tried the solution from here

[Is there an easy way to check the .NET Framework version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951856/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-net-framework-verison-using-c)

It gives the highest version installed but I need the running version.

Comment: Have you looked at the Properties of the project?  The targeted framework version is available there.

Comment: `System.Environment.Version.ToString()` is this what you are interested in ? or you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420941/why-cant-i-display-the-asp-net-framework-version-as-3-5

Answer (score 9):

Use **`Environment.Version`** for getting the run time version. It will give the version number of .Net CLR which is being used for executing current application.

You need to be careful here, it will only return run time version not framework version. The CLR for .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 is the same CLR from .NET 2.0.

Comment: but isn't there a way to get the version like 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: You will have to calculate that using the information you get with Environment.Version

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Environment.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx) - it gives you the exact version of .NET running the application.

Answer (score -6):

Hope this one helps,

```
DirectoryEntry site = new DirectoryEntry(@"IIS://localhost/w3svc/1/Root");
PropertyValueCollection values = site.Properties["ScriptMaps"];
foreach (string val in values)
{
    if (val.StartsWith(".aspx"))
    {
        string version = val.Substring(val.IndexOf("Framework") + 10, 9);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ASP.Net Version is {0}", version));
    }
}
```

The script map property is an array of strings. If the app supports asp.net one of those strings will be a mapping of the aspx file extension to the asp.net handler which will a the full path to a DLL. The path will be something like

> %windir%/Microsoft.NET/Framework//aspnet_isapi.dll.

You can get the version out of this string with some simple parsing.

Comment: I really wish people would explain why they downvote something.I have to assume this is because it's not really answering the question.

Comment: @Hammerstein - Personally its because mhn just posted code without any explaination or anything.