# How to show an error message window when the target usr doesn't have the .NET Framework version used in application?

Tags: c#, error-handling, frameworks

I am creating applications with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and since it is the latest release most of the target computers have old versions of the framework.

I want soemthing like this

```
try
{
//Code to see if framework that user have is .NET Framework 4.5.1 
}

catch
{
// Code to show a window to user that offers downloading .NET Framework 4.5.1 
}
```

It should not necessarily be in this format but this is just to express my thought. Any affort would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Here's a similar question answered.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519478/get-the-current-dot-net-version-of-my-application

Comment: @vikramjb yeah that seems like pretty much the solution.

Comment: Yeap there you go, problem solved !!

Comment: @vikramjb and I figured out this is half of the solution. It gives the  runtime version of my application. Now I need the target computer's version.

Comment: The biggest mistake you made is not actually trying it.  The first time a user runs your program, it will automatically prompt the user to get the .NET version it needs.  Do not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my .NET 4 application know .NET 4 is not installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032233/why-does-my-net-4-application-know-net-4-is-not-installed)